# Firebase CLI: how to get version for an apk from app distribution

Tags: android, firebase, jenkins, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have uploaded couple of apk to firebase via app distribution cli command, which I am running via Firebase CLI + Jenkins.

Now its possible sometime we upload some binary explicitly to firebase manually, like client release or test few things and we change the version.

Is it possible to pull what's the latest binary version on firebase so that I can update mine while generating via Jenkins.

Thanks,

I tried using Firebase CLI, apps:list it return the apps but post that what command needs to run.

I tired with REST API, but it require OAuth token, for which I have to write explicitly node/java/python program to get token and then call the REST API and then parse the data then update the version. Seems problematic as token may get expired and then I have rebuild again, its also quite a step for a getting a build version, hence looking for something simpler or less steps.